# Inotify does not work on EFS (remote filesystem)

Tags: inotify, amazon-efs

I tried to use inotify notifications, to check for filesystem events, but it does not work. no file-system vent notifier worked.

Is there any inotify utility available for remote file system like EFS, NFS, GFS etc?

Comment: Is the write occurring on the same host that is trying to get notifications?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, no.  inotify works by hooking into the kernels 'write' code. As remote filesystems have the ability for other things to write to them, without the kernel being aware of it, inotify explicitly does not work for them.

For more information, there's a useful overview here:

https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/linux-filesystem-events-inotify